# How do I if/or in php?

Tags: php, if-statement

How do I make this work? It feels super jumbled and it is not working for three statements, only two.

Can I do something like:

```
  <?php if (((($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == $darkscheme or $june or $breaking)) echo 'class="white"'; ?>
```

Instead of what I have now:

```
<?php if (((($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == $darkscheme)) or (($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == $breaking)) or (($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == $june)) echo 'class="white"'; ?>
```

Comment: try `if(in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], [$darkscheme, $june, $breaking])) {}`

Comment: Hi William! thanks, but where do I add the "echo" ?

Comment: What is contained in `$darkscheme`, `$june` and `$breaking`? Are those _really_ dynamic values or more like constants?

Comment: Hi guys, William, you got this one. I added yours and it worked. Do you want to add it as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: That way I can add you as the correct?

Answer (score 3):

Create an array of all your elements, and then check if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` exists in the array with `in_array()`.

```
<?php 
if (in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], [$darkscheme, $june, $breaking])) 
    echo 'class="white"'; 
?>
```

Note that this is *case-sensitive*.

- [PHP.net on `in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can this method ternary opertator.

```
<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == $darkscheme) ? ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == $breaking) ? ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == $june) : echo 'class="white"' ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than using `in_array` as mentioned, just some basic formatting and not using unnecessary parentheses could make it less "jumbled" and probably fix the issue of it only working for 2 of the three. Also you should consider using `===` (or passing in true as a third parameter for `in_array`) which could also fix truthy/falsey problems you might be facing.

eg:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === $darkscheme || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === $breaking || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === $june) {
    echo 'class="white"';
}
```

or even

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === $darkscheme || 
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === $breaking || 
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === $june) 
{
    echo 'class="white"';
}
```